Cannot borrow `p` as mutable more than once at a time
I'm trying to figure out exactly why I get this compile error in this very simple code;

cannot borrow p as mutable more than once at a time

as I do not store p more than once mutably; either directly or indirectly, as far as i can see.
fn main() {
    println!("Running...");

    let a = Element {
        tag_name: String::from("p"),
        parent_node: None,
    };
    let b = Element {
        tag_name: String::from("p"),
        parent_node: None,
    };
    let mut p = Node {
        id: String::from("id-p"),
        first_child: None,
    };
    p.append_child(a);
    p.append_child(b);
}

struct Element<'a> {
    tag_name: String,
    parent_node: Option<&'a Node<'a>>,
}

impl Element<'_> {
    // ..more to come..
}

struct Node<'a> {
    id: String,
    first_child: Option<Box<Element<'a>>>,
}

impl<'a> Node<'a> {
    fn append_child(&'a mut self, node: Element<'a>) {
        let node = Some(Box::new(node));
        self.first_child = node
    }
}

The second call to append_child is the problem, even tho the first call doesn't create any references to self. Neither is anything returned from append_child.
If I removed the parent_node field from Element (and all the associated lifetime annotations), the problem goes away, even tho I never assigned to it;
fn main() {
    println!("Running...");

    let a = Element {
        tag_name: String::from("p"),
        // parent_node: None,
    };
    let b = Element {
        tag_name: String::from("p"),
        // parent_node: None,
    };
    let mut p = Node {
        id: String::from("id-p"),
        first_child: None,
    };
    p.append_child(a);
    p.append_child(b);
}

struct Element {
    tag_name: String,
    // parent_node: Option<&'a Node<'a>>,
}

impl Element {
    // ..more to come..
}

struct Node {
    id: String,
    first_child: Option<Box<Element>>,
}

impl Node {
    fn append_child(& mut self, node: Element) {
        let node = Some(Box::new(node));
        self.first_child = node
    }
}

Is the compiler simply saying that, the mere existence of the parent_node field 'could' store a reference to self, therefore creating this compile time problem?

TL;DR: &'a mut T<'a> is always wrong; remove the 'a in &'a mut self.

got it :) thanks

It also looks suspiciously like you'd want parent_node to reference the Node containing the Element. That would create a self-referential data structure that doesn't play well with lifetimes. See Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?

Yes, but if I box<> the parent_node field doesn't that break this link by making the two nodes separate heap allocated structs?
